How to capture Subscriberkey in Text response in mobile connect
we have sent outbound message and capturing mobile number and subscriberkey into data data extension and now when user responds to outbound with keyword Accept, we need to update the response to salesforce object based on subscriberkey and Mobile number
below is the code in text response
%%[
SET @Keyword = 'Accepted'SET @Id  = RequestParameter("Offer_Detail__c:Id")
SET @Mobilenumber = RequestParameter("Offer_Detail__c:Guarantor_Phone__c")
SET @Updatestatus = UpdateSingleSalesforceObject('Offer_Detail__c', @Id,'Status__c', @Response )
]%%

Thank you for your response, we are working on your request.
The above code is not working and its not updating the salesforce. Any sugession please?

In Mobile Connect one phone number can be assigned to multiple contacts, so there's no out of the box way to have the Contact Key provided.
It's up to you to match the phone number (from which the incoming text is sent) with your customer data.
Use any Ampscript lookup function that suits you or retrieve the phone number from your CRM directly if it's a better source of truth of who the current phone number owner is.
